# How to retrieve Browser name, browser version, application version, and application name in Restful WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

How to retrieve Browser name, browser version, application version, and application name in Restful WCF Service? The function that will evaluate above info, gets an argument as System.ServiceModel.Channel.Message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your application sends that information in a custom HTTP header, you'll be able to retrieve it by looking at the `HttpRequestMessageProperty`, which you can retrieve from the message object by going to its properties:

```
private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetHttpHeaders(Message msg)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    var prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)msg.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
    foreach (var headerName in prop.Headers.AllKeys)
    {
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            headerName,
            prop.Headers[headerName]);
    }

    return result;
}
```